# Using If statement to initialise an image

Tags: ios, xcode

So I've got a dictionary which stores the number 0 at all 100 locations but I want to then use these 0s to initialise 100 images with no image. Later on the images will change when a different number replaces the stored 0 (i.e. 1). I have the following code, which all works until the last line:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i ++) {
    if(myDict)
    {
        [myDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"block%.3istored",i]];
    }
}
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"blocks.save"];
BOOL successfulWrite = [myDict writeToFile: path atomically: YES];
if(successfulWrite == NO);

[myDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"block002stored"];

for (int z = 1; z <= 100; z ++) {

    NSString *mapblock=@"mapblock";
    NSString *blocktocheck=[mapblock stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",z];

    NSLog(@"%d", z);
    NSLog(@"%@", blocktocheck);

    {if (forKey:@"block%.3zstored" == 0) [@"%@", blocktocheck].image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@""];
```

}

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a closing bracket missing from your code? You have an open bracket before the if and no close after it.

Answer (score 0):

2 things.

1. you miss the object to send check... >> if (forKey:@"block....
2. you need to set a valid key >> @"block%.3zstored"

change it to

```
for (int z = 1; z <= 100; z ++) {
    NSString *mapblock=@"mapblock";
    NSString *blocktocheck=[mapblock stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",z];
    id key = blocktocheck;

    if ([myDict objectForKey:key] == nil) {
         [myDict setObject:img forKey:key];
     }
 }
```

Comment: That gives me an undeclared identifier 'img'. Also, I'd like to actually set an image (i.e. block1.png) where I currently have @"".